# How to filter array of object based on another array values using javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have a simple array of numbers (which for my app represents user Id's). For example...

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

I also have an array of objects such as

```
[
    {Id: 1, FirstName: "Bob", LastName: "Jones", EmailAddress: "bob@bob.com"},
    {Id: 2, FirstName: "Tessa", LastName: "Wong", EmailAddress: "tes@wong.com"},
    {Id: 3, FirstName: "Craig", LastName: "Murray", EmailAddress: "Craig@muz.com"},
    {Id: 4, FirstName: "Bryce", LastName: "Willamson", EmailAddress: "email@me.com"},
    {Id: 5, FirstName: "Tony", LastName: "Ocka", EmailAddress: "toni@oz.com"}
]
```

What I need to do is match any values that appear in the initial array with they key `Id` in the second array of objects (and return a new full array of objects containing only matches). So for example in this case, the result I'm looking for is:

```
[
    {Id: 1, FirstName: "Bob", LastName: "Jones", EmailAddress: "bob@bob.com"},
    {Id: 2, FirstName: "Tessa", LastName: "Wong", EmailAddress: "tes@wong.com"},
    {Id: 3, FirstName: "Craig", LastName: "Murray", EmailAddress: "Craig@muz.com"},
]
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's always good to show your attempt in OP to help fellow users to understand where you are stuck.

You can use "Array.filter" and "includes" for this.

```js
let arr1 = [1,2,3]

let arr2 = [
    {Id: 1, FirstName: "Bob", LastName: "Jones", EmailAddress: "bob@bob.com"},
    {Id: 2, FirstName: "Tessa", LastName: "Wong", EmailAddress: "tes@wong.com"},
    {Id: 3, FirstName: "Craig", LastName: "Murray", EmailAddress: "Craig@muz.com"},
    {Id: 4, FirstName: "Bryce", LastName: "Willamson", EmailAddress: "email@me.com"},
    {Id: 5, FirstName: "Tony", LastName: "Ocka", EmailAddress: "toni@oz.com"}
]

let result = arr2.filter(d => arr1.includes(d.Id))

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick reply and elegant solution. I'll be sure to add my attempt in next time as suggested. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Also you can do this by iterating through the second array

```js
let arr1 = [1,2,3];

let arr2 = [
    {Id: 1, FirstName: "Bob", LastName: "Jones", EmailAddress: "bob@bob.com"},
    {Id: 2, FirstName: "Tessa", LastName: "Wong", EmailAddress: "tes@wong.com"},
    {Id: 3, FirstName: "Craig", LastName: "Murray", EmailAddress: "Craig@muz.com"},
    {Id: 4, FirstName: "Bryce", LastName: "Willamson", EmailAddress: "email@me.com"},
    {Id: 5, FirstName: "Tony", LastName: "Ocka", EmailAddress: "toni@oz.com"}
]

let result = [];
for(let i in arr2) {
    if(arr1.indexOf(arr2[i].Id)!==-1) result.push(arr2[i]);
}

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Set` to optimize your performance. The lookup operation of an array takes `O(n)` which increases the overall time complexity of your function to O(n^2) whereas lookup operation in `Set` takes `O(1)` so overall time complexity is O(n).

```js
let arr1 = [1,2,3]

let set = new Set(arr1);

let arr2 = [ {Id: 1, FirstName: "Bob", LastName: "Jones", EmailAddress: "bob@bob.com"}, {Id: 2, FirstName: "Tessa", LastName: "Wong", EmailAddress: "tes@wong.com"}, {Id: 3, FirstName: "Craig", LastName: "Murray", EmailAddress: "Craig@muz.com"}, {Id: 4, FirstName: "Bryce", LastName: "Willamson", EmailAddress: "email@me.com"}, {Id: 5, FirstName: "Tony", LastName: "Ocka", EmailAddress: "toni@oz.com"}];

let result = arr2.filter(({Id}) => set.has(Id))

console.log(result)
```